# Need Redirect To Remove Article ID String

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, joomla1.5

I'm hoping someone can help. I am looking for a redirect rule for url's like this...
www.site.com/chevy/234-article-name
www.site.com/ford/98-article-name
www.site.com/kia/5-article-name

I need to remove the "#-" portion, where the # is the article ID. So in any given catagory, each article has it's ID in front of the article name.
I have recently changed url structure and need to redirect several hundred url's.
Yes, it is a Joomla thing. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a rewrite rule to handle the job:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/[\d]*-(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: OK. It worked great, but i found one problem i did not foresee. Is there a way to exclude a certain catagory from using this rewrite. Example... http://www.website.com/multimedia/5-pontiac/detail/46-pontiac-g8-pic redirects to website/multimedia

Comment: I've edited the regex to be lazy (.+?) instead of greedy (.*).  I should get out of the habit of using .* -- See if that works better for you...

Comment: Still problem with certain urls. Any way to keep these with ID numbers in them? In know it is asking a lot, but worth the ask...    http://www.website.com/multimedia/13-repair-videos/detail/140-check-car-fues-video